# wamp - what is the "C:/wamp/tmp/session_dir" file? Can I delete it?

Tags: wamp, session-variables

In the **"C:/wamp/tmp/"** folder (where session files are stored),
I have one file named **session_dir**, that contents only this text:

```
session directory
```

What is it? Can I delete it?

Comment: Did you consider just renaming it to see if something breaks? That would tell you pretty easily whether it needs to be there or not, and do so much more quickly than asking here and waiting for an answer.

Comment: If you 'Stop all services' then delete everything in the `\wamp\tmp` and the `Restart all Services` If something in Apache/PHP/MySQL requires that file it will recreate it. Otherwise its not necessary. It is a folder to hold temporary files, so anything in there should be temporary.

Answer (score 2):

The default Wamp installation has this line in php.ini :

```
session.save_path = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

You can remove the file you mentionned. In your future devs, if you use sessions, you should find some session files in this dir.